# Propositional logic: Proof question (p∧q)→r⊢(p→q)→r

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

Am I correct to assume that there is no proof for $$(p∧q)→r ⊢ (p→q)→r$$ 
I´ve spent hours trying to figure it out, by now I suspect there might have been a mistake in the exercise. I have been able to proof
$$(p∧q)→r ⊢ p→(q→r)$$ (using Fitch notation), so it seems unlikely to me that 
$$(p∧q)→r ⊢ (p→q)→r$$ is valid as well. I´m quite new to propositional logic, so I just wanted to ask whether my reasoning is sound!

Comment: May I ask what is the meaning of that left sided t symbol ?

Comment: @Leth It refers to provability or derivability. That is, when we say $\Gamma \vdash \phi$, we say that we can derive $\phi$ from the set of statements $\Gamma$.  Technically, you would need to specify what proof system you are referring to, since theoretically what is provable in one proof system may not be what is provable in another. In practice, though, we typically assume that the proof system is sound and complete and, as such, $\Gamma \vdash \phi$ amounts to the same thing as $\Gamma \vDash \phi$, i.e. logical consequence.

Comment: @Bram28 Got it, thanks a lot.

Comment: P ⊢ Q derivability (Q can be derived from P)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's correct. There is no proof, because $p = F$ and $r = F$ is a counterexample to the argument.

And by the way, just because you have

$$(p \land q) \rightarrow r \vdash p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r)$$

does *not* mean that you would not have

$$(p \land q) \rightarrow r \vdash (p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow r$$

even if $p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r)$ is not the same as $(p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow r$.

For example: we have that $p \land q \vdash p$ ... but does that mean that *therefore* we don't have $p \land q \vdash q$ (because $p$ is not $q$)? Clearly not.

Comment: Thanks for the added explanation! :) Creating a truth table would be the fastest way to find out whether the formulae are logically equivalent I guess - but that didn´t occur to me earlier, because I thought that there has to be a proof for (p∧q)→r⊢p→(q→r) since the example is from an old exam...

Comment: @LittleD You're welcome!  A truth-table would show you that $p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r)$ and $(p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow r$ are not equiv., but that $p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r)$ and $(p \land q) \rightarrow r$ are, and hence that $(p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow r$ and $(p \land q) \rightarrow r$ are not. But more importantly, it would show you that $(p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow r$ is not a logical consequence of $(p \land q) \rightarrow r$ (because in the two rows where $p = F$ and $r =F$, you'll find that $(p \land q) \rightarrow r = T$ but $(p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow r = F$

Comment: I think you'd need to assign a truth value to q also to have a counterexample.  But, either truth value here works, so at least two counterexamples exist.

Comment: What is the value of $q$ in your counterexample?

Answer (score 0):

There is no proof because the tableau of $\lnot (((p\land q)\to r)\to ((p\to q)\to r)))$ is not closed.